# Flutter Initialize the riverpod class

Tags: flutter, riverpod

How can I pass id to class Foo

This is class Foo

```
@riverpod
class Foo extends _$Foo {
  final String id;

  @override
  bool build() {
    return id == 'abc';
  }
}
```

I use the following command to get value from Foo

```
ref.watch(fooProvider);
```

But I don't know how to pass the id to Foo.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: The build() should get id from another provider or from a global variable, not a parameter.  If you have many providers that need to be alive at the same time, use a family provider to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
ref.watch(fooProvider.notifier).update();
```

Or you should StateNotifierProvider.